# VConfig error: cannot add vlan interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vlan

I started working with VLAN kernel capabilities only recently and found a pretty challenging domain.

I thought I had almost everything in control but then found a problem which I am apparently unable to solve.

I have some automatic scripts taking care of creating and destroying some *network namespaces* which must isolate a user domain from one another.

In one of my servers, this script has been properly working for 2 months now, but suddenly today it started misbehaving in a very odd way. Kernel version is **3.13.0-24-generic** running within **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**.

This is the current situation:

```
cat /proc/net/vlan/config

VLAN Dev name    | VLAN ID
Name-Type: VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
```

So nothing there.

```
ip netns ls

TEST
```

That is my namespace is still there.

```
ip netns exec TEST cat /proc/net/vlan/config

VLAN Dev name    | VLAN ID
Name-Type: VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
tap0.105       | 105  | tap0
```

I have defined a virtual tagged interface in this domain, which is properly configured and correctly running.

```
ip netns exec TEST ip addr

1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
92: tap0.105@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc 
      noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 5a:ff:b5:98:6f:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.51.1/32 scope global tap0.105
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::58ff:b5ff:fe98:6fc2/64 scope link 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Then the problem:

```
vconfig add eth1 10

ERROR: trying to add VLAN #10 to IF -:eth1:-  error: File exists
```

and, of course:

```
vconfig rem eth1.10

ERROR: trying to remove VLAN -:eth1.10:- error: No such device
```

I tried to look on the internet for similar error cases but with no success. Some other outputs:

```
ip netns pids TEST
```

gives no result.

This is an STRACE of the command:

`root@d-intfw1:~# strace vconfig add eth1 10
execve("/sbin/vconfig", ["vconfig", "add", "eth1", "10"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1a2a000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f361112c000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=24418, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 24418, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3611126000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1845024, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3953344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3610b46000
mprotect(0x7f3610d02000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3610f01000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bb000) = 0x7f3610f01000
mmap(0x7f3610f07000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3610f07000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3611125000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3611123000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f3611123740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3610f01000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x601000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f361112e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f3611126000, 24418)           = 0
open("/proc/net/vlan/config", O_RDONLY) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFVLAN, 0x7fffeead1420)   = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
write(2, "ERROR: trying to add VLAN #10 to"..., 65ERROR: trying to add VLAN #10 to IF -:eth1:-  error: File exists
) = 65
exit_group(3)                           = ?
+++ exited with 3 +++`

Does anyone know what the cause might be for such a behaviour?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: strace `vconfig rem eth1.10`.?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue and how?  Could you share if you did?

Comment: Hi @Lifeboy, I finally understood that whenever this happens, there's likely a process having "something to do" (likely an open file descriptor) with that namespace which is still hanging there (in a non-well defined environment, since the namespace does not exist anymore).

Terminating the culprit should be enough, but discovering its identity may not be the simplest quest ever (I once had a strongswan daemon running bound to that netns, which I forgot to stop before deleting the netns).